# Excel MATCH and SUMIF Formula Not Matching Wxact Matches

Tags: excel, match, sumifs, exact-match, excel-match

I have a sheet with exact values (verified by `=a2=b2` returning `true`).

However, `=match(a2,b2,0)` returns `#N/A` for some values, but not all.

All cells are formatted the same (I've tried General, Text, Number, etc.), and I have no idea where to go from here.

I don't know if I can upload my test workbook here so here's an image:

[image]

Comment: What formula have you used in column D to verify that A=B?

Comment: What is the purpose of your MATCH formula? Using MATCH just to compare the two values is possible but a simple IF will do the same in this case.

Comment: @Gabor True from a practical point of view, but the theoretical point remains of interest, in my opinion, i.e. if =A2=B2 returns TRUE, why should =MATCH(A2,B2,0) error?

Comment: @XOR LX, from a theoretical point of view I'm curious as well. It would be good to see the actual file, or at least the formulas in the file. Can you post another picture where you show the formulas in the cells?

Comment: @XORLX  [here](http://imgur.com/a/rKESM) and [here](http://imgur.com/a/l1fjc)

Comment: Why does your title contain a reference to the function SUMIF?

Comment: Also, are you set to Automatic Calculation mode (File/Options/Formulas)?

Comment: @XORLX I originally came across the problem using SUMIF and while investigating condensed it into this smaller sheet. In retrospect mentioning SUMIF was unnecessary. My apologies. And yes I do have automatic calc on

Comment: If you go into the formula bar for one of the cells containing a MATCH formula which errors, then press ENTER, does the result change?

Comment: @XORLX it recalculates the error.

Comment: For one of those errors, can you post a screenshot of the Evaluate Formula box (Formulas tab) after having pressed the Evaluate button a single time (but not a second)?

Comment: @XORLX http://imgur.com/a/SDc9A

so it looks like the error is with the b column?

Comment: What are the cell formats for cells A2 and B2?

Comment: @XORLX right now they are "General" but I've tried changing both of them to almost every possible combination

Comment: Ok, we'll get there! Can you also post a screenshot of the Evaluate Formula box for the formula =A2=B2, though this time having pressed the Evaluate button twice?

Comment: @XORLX Thanks for all your help! http://imgur.com/02fkess

EDIT: Oops... don't know what happened there... here is the non messed up version http://imgur.com/a/s4xr8

Comment: Thanks. And if you go into the formula bar for that formula and press ENTER, do you still get TRUE as the return?

Comment: @XORLX Yep. If I click evaluate once more it still says TRUE as well

Comment: Are the entries in A2 and B2 static values, or the results of formulas in those cells? Also, do you currently have any circular references within any open workbooks?

Comment: @XORLX Completely static. They were originally results of a formula but I have long since copy>pasted values. Also this is currently my only workbook open however I did get an error message about circular references earlier today.

Comment: Do you still have that circular reference? (It should say in the bottom-right of your Excel window, or you can also go to Formulas/Error Checking/Circular References.) Sorry, bottom-left, I believe.

Comment: I do not still have the circular reference but when I went to error checking it said I had a trace error and when I clicked on it, it drew these lines http://imgur.com/a/ZzatC

Comment: Honestly, I would need to see your file directly to see what is going on in there. I've done a test with the same numbers and everything works fine for me.

Comment: Can you please, do one more thing: Go to the Formulas tab, look for the Formula Auditing section and click the Show Formulas button. Then, send another screenshot of your table.

Comment: @Gabor I would love to upload the file but I'm not 100% sure on what the rules are for that. If I could just upload it to a file sharing website and that would be allowed please let me know. Here is your screenshot http://imgur.com/DGbdt6x

Comment: I think you can put it on a sharing site and paste a link

Comment: @Gabor https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1XzwlJsvJIoZ0F3Y01aRndqOHM/view

Comment: Thanks for the file. I did a little test. When I go into both Value1 and Value2 cells on row 2, and hit Enter in both of them, it gets recalculated and the proper value shows up in Match. It might be some formatting issue that is related to where the data came from originally. I have experienced this before, and this is very annoying indeed.

Comment: @Gabor Do you know of a way to fix this without manually hitting enter? I have thousands of lines that have this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe run a quick macro on the relevant cells in columns A and B:

```
Sub Clean_Up()

For Each r In Range("A2:B8")
    r.Value = Val(r.Value)
Next r

End Sub
```

Adjust range (`A2:B8` here) to suit.

Regards